# After creating Expo dev build getting Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: firebase, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, eas

I am trying to incorporate push notifications into my Expo app by linking Apple Push Notification Service (APN) with Firebase Cloud Messaging service (FCM) in my iOS app. My understanding is that it's best to test this functionality on a development build so I have downloaded a build I did with EAS to my iPhone. The build was successful and I can attempt to run it on my device using the expo dev client but I keep getting an error message in the terminal:

`Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()`

My `firebaseConfig` is in an `index.ts` file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

// import { getAnalytics } from "expo-firebase-analytics"

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
}

// Initialize Firebase
export const startFirebase = () => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

and I'm calling the `startFirebase()` function from my `app.tsx` file:

```
import "./i18n"
import "./utils/ignore-warnings"
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { SafeAreaProvider, initialWindowMetrics } from "react-native-safe-area-context"
import { initFonts } from "./theme/fonts" // expo
import * as storage from "./utils/storage"
import { AppNavigator, useNavigationPersistence } from "./navigators"
import { RootStore, RootStoreProvider, setupRootStore } from "./models"
import { ErrorBoundary } from "./screens/error/error-boundary"
import { PersonaProvider } from "./context/PersonaContext"
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen"
import { startFirebase } from "./services/firebase"
import { Alert, Platform } from "react-native"
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications"
import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging"

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
})

export const NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY = "NAVIGATION_STATE"

function App() {

  const [rootStore, setRootStore] = useState<RootStore | undefined>(undefined)
  const {
    initialNavigationState,
    onNavigationStateChange,
    isRestored: isNavigationStateRestored,
  } = useNavigationPersistence(storage, NAVIGATION_PERSISTENCE_KEY)
  
  startFirebase()

  const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission()
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL

    if (enabled) {
      console.log("Authorization status:", authStatus)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // const authStatus = async () =>  await messaging().requestPermission()
    if (requestUserPermission()) {
      // return fcm token from the device
      messaging()
        .getToken()
        .then((token) => {
          console.log("token received:", token)
        })
    } else {
      console.log("failed token status")
    }

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(async (remoteMessage) => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            "Notification caused app to open from quit state:",
            remoteMessage.notification,
          )
        }
      })

    // Assume a message-notification contains a "type" property in the data payload of the screen to open

    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(
        "Notification caused app to open from background state:",
        remoteMessage.notification,
      )
      // navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
    })

    // Register background handler
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log("Message handled in the background!", remoteMessage)
    })

    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      Alert.alert("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage))
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])



  // Kick off initial async loading actions, like loading fonts and RootStore
  useEffect(() => {
    async function prepare() {
      try {
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
        await initFonts() // expo
        setupRootStore().then(setRootStore)
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e)
      } finally {
        await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
      }
    }
    prepare()
  }, [])

  if (!rootStore || !isNavigationStateRestored) return null

  return (
    // <ToggleStorybook>
    <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
      <SafeAreaProvider initialMetrics={initialWindowMetrics}>
        <ErrorBoundary catchErrors={"always"}>
          <PersonaProvider>
            <AppNavigator
              initialState={initialNavigationState}
              onStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            />
          </PersonaProvider>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </RootStoreProvider>
    // </ToggleStorybook>
  )
}

export default App
```

This app had been using a Firebase realtime database as well before I started to incorporate the push notifications and everything was working fine. Somehow the changes I've made have resulted in this error. Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks!